# aura:token not working in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to use some default CSS tokens for coloring components.

As per the [Developer Guide documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_standard.htm):

> To add the standard tokens to your org, extend a tokens bundle from the base tokens, like so.
>
> `<aura:tokens extends="force:base">
>       <!-- your own tokens here -->
>   </aura:tokens>`

However this immediately gives the following error on save:

> Failed to save undefined: markup://c:MyComponent:18,39: Invalid attribute "extends": Source

Is this functionality currently broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use token in Lightning components instead of **Lightning Tokens**.

Go to Developer Console and select Lightning Token from New > Lightning Tokens:-
[image]

This is how we reference tokens once saved.

```
.THIS p {
    font-family: token(fontFamily); /* fontFamily is token name */
    font-weight: token(fontWeightRegular);
}
```

Comment: I want to use the default tokens that match the SLDS though, which is what the linked documentation says I should be able to do?

Comment: @nicstella save your token file as `defaultTokens`. It would automatically inherit all standard tokens. In addition you can add your token within the tag.

Comment: Ok I see what I was doing wrong. I have now created the Lightning .tokens bundle. Do I need to reference it from the component trying to use it somehow? I am now receiving the error "No TOKEN named colorBackgroundError found".

Comment: It is better to create your own by seeing standard css because as per this doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_standard_force_base.htm Salesforce doesn't guarantee availability of tokens. @nicstella

Comment: That list contains `colorBackgroundError`, which isn't working. It is better if I don't want things to change, but not if I want my colours to update with the SLDS.

Comment: @nicstella looks like tokens present in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_standard_communities.htm are available by default only.

Comment: Thank you Ashwani - the documentation is quite unclear in most places